# Problem with launching the gazebo

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm a new user in Gazebo, I had program to launch the gazebo in my Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 64bit system. It will stuck at preparing your world. It's this due to my computer's problem or some configuration problem?

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14237/problem-with-launching-the-gazebo/) by [Zero.J](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2776/zero.j/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-08-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The first time you launch Gazebo, it tries to download some models from the internet. If you wait a while it will eventually start.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zero.J](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2776/zero.j/) on 2016-08-25**:
Thank you. you are right, I can use it now.

**Comment by [spacejunkie](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3030/spacejunkie/) on 2017-01-31**:
How long do you have to wait? I have the same problem and have been waiting for hours.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-01-31**:
It usually depends on your internet connection, but I don't think it should ever wait for hours.

**Comment by [Qdesign](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3051/qdesign/) on 2017-02-10**:
having the same problem and I'v been wait for almost more than 2 hours for now...is that normal?

**Comment by [fmazzi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3676/fmazzi/) on 2017-08-04**:
I have the same problem with gazebo 7.8 and ubuntu 16.04.3, somebody figured out how to fix it?